# How to Auto Scale Unity Objects according to given values.?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a line graph in my Unity game. 
Graph draws according to the values given through a list.
But when the value goes high the coordinate goes out of the screen, How can I scale down my graph when a large value comes?

[image: This is how graph looks like with a large value.]

I used this code to scale down the graph, but it scales down only when last value of the list is large.

```
public void ChangeScale(){
    Debug.Log (valueList [valueList.Count-1]);
    temp = graphContainer.localScale;
    if (valueList [valueList.Count - 1]>600) {

        temp.x -= 1f;
        temp.y -= 1f;
        graphContainer.localScale = new Vector2 (temp.x, temp.y);
        //temp.Set(temp.x+0.05f,temp.y+0.05f,0);
        Debug.Log (temp.x);
        Debug.Log (temp.y);
    }

    if (valueList [valueList.Count - 1]>1000) {

        temp.x -= 0.6f;
        temp.y -= 0.6f;
        graphContainer.localScale = new Vector2 (temp.x, temp.y);
        //temp.Set(temp.x+0.05f,temp.y+0.05f,0);
        Debug.Log (temp.x);
        Debug.Log (temp.y);
    }
    if (valueList [valueList.Count - 1]>1600) {

        temp.x -= 0.3f;
        temp.y -= 0.3f;
        graphContainer.localScale = new Vector2 (temp.x, temp.y);
        //temp.Set(temp.x+0.05f,temp.y+0.05f,0);
        Debug.Log (temp.x);
        Debug.Log (temp.y);
    }
    Debug.Log (temp.x);
    Debug.Log (temp.y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq

```
using System.Linq;

//....

if(valueList.Exists(i => i > 600))
{
    //...
}
```

This turns true if any of the elements in the `valueList` matches the given condition, in this case `>600`.

---

Alternatively you can also just get the biggest of all elements:

```
var bigggestElement = valueList.OrderByDescending().First();
```

Or simply

```
var biggest = valueList.Max();
```

and check only that

```
if(biggest > 600)
{
    //...
}
```

---

And now you actually could/should somehow normalize the graph depending on the value of `biggest` instead of searching in certain intervals (`600`, `1000`, ...).